# what is /media/catalog/product/N/o/NoImages100_184x.jpg and why is it growing?

Tags: cron, security, magento-1.7.0.1

We were running out of space on our server so we did a search for large files we could delete and found one in htdocs/media/catalog/product/N/o/ called "NoImages100_184x.jpg" which was 112MB. It was also present in our test environments in sizes varying from 60-240MB. My web guy and I had no idea what this was, so we downloaded the file to both a Mac and PC and tried to open it. No luck. Said that file was corrupt or the wrong file type. So, we deleted the file. And it reappeared with 600 permissions and owned by the webserver user. Instantly. Small, just a couple of k. Then it started growing. 5k, 6k, 7k, 8k, 9k, etc. I did a tail -f on the file and there was a line getting written to it just about every second. Most of the lines looked like this:

"YToxOntzOjI6ImlkIjtzOjg6Ilc5SE03SDhCIjt9LS1hOjA6e30="

with 10 characters to the right of center changing each time it was written, but the rest of the line remaining the same. The file has no header, just starts right in with those cryptic lines, just like a log file.

I ran ClamAV and found no viruses or anything. I grepped my Magento installation looking for a file that referenced the jpg filename, but found nothing.

Finally I just changed permissions on the file to 400, and it stopped growing.

I did tail -f on the file in one of our test environments and it was static. Of course, the test environment doesn't have traffic and cron is not running. Even so, I tried loading some webpages, and running cron.php from the browser, and the file remained static.

Web searches for the filename, the directory name, related keywords, stuff like "growing JPG file yielded no results. We searches for some of the strings inside the file likewise were fruitless.

Can anybody shed some light on this. I'm more than a little freaked out.

Comment: the tale of the expanding jpg... sound spooky to me. :c

Comment: Can you list out your extensions? Who is your host? Have you read this? http://blog.nexcess.net/2014/07/25/recent-exploit-using-fake-magento-extensions/

Comment: btw it is base64 a:1:{s:2:"id";s:8:"W9HM7H8B";}--a:0:{}
reminds you of anything?

Comment: Oh wow. I hadn't seen that. It looks like almost EXACTLY what happened to us. We didn't use any of those listed extensions at any time, but we have a LOT of extensions. I'll list the modules below if you want to look over them for suggestions. It looks like the exploit is running, but not actually working correctly probably because we have upgraded our core files, so the core files seem clean. The JPG file doesn't seem to contain the information that this article says we should be able to see. We are hosting with Peer 1, a dedicated server.

Comment: Aitoc_Aitinfusion.xml            Mage_Oauth.xml
Aitoc_Aitinstall.xml             Mage_PageCache.xml
Aitoc_Aitstabilityguard.xml      Mage_Persistent.xml
Amasty_Base.xml                  Mage_Weee.xml
Amasty_Methods.xml               Mage_Widget.xml
Anaraky_Gdrt.xml                 Mage_XmlConnect.xml
AW_Advancedreports.xml           Magpleasure_Adminlogger.xml
AW_All.xml                       Magpleasure_Common.xml
AW_ARUnitNewvsreturning.xml      Magpleasure_Info.xml
AW_ARUnitSalesbycouponcode.xml   MDN_AdvancedStock.xml
AW_ARUnitSalesbypaymenttype.xml  MDN_Amazon.xml

Comment: AW_ARUnitSalesbypaymenttype.xml  MDN_Amazon.xml
AW_Core.xml                      MDN_BackgroundTask.xml
AW_Followupemail.xml             MDN_ExtensionConflict.xml
AW_Helpdeskultimate.xml          MDN_HealthyERP.xml
AW_Kbase.xml                     MDN_MarketPlace.xml
AW_Mobile.xml                    MDN_Orderpreparation.xml
AW_Productquestions.xml          MDN_Organizer.xml
AW_Reviewrotator.xml             MDN_Purchase.xml
AW_Vidtest.xml                   MDN_SalesOrderPlanning.xml
AW_Zblocks.xml                   MDN_Scanner.xml
Bluejalappeno_Orderexport.xml    Mirasvit_FeedExport.x

Comment: DataFeedWatch_Connector.xml      Mirasvit_MstCore.xml                          NetAmbition_DirectResize.xml     Phoenix_Moneybookers.xml
Dull_Uploader.xml                StorePickup_Shipping.xml
Ebizmarts_SagePaymentsCE.xml     Sureclient_Echeck.xml
EcommerceTeam_CloudZoom.xml      TBT_Billboard.xml
EmailDirect_Integration.xml      TBT_Common.xml
Evolved_Like.xml                 TBT_InHouseDefaults.xml
Excellence_AjaxWishlist.xml      TBT_Milestone.xml
Excellence_Ajax.xml              TBT_RewardsApi.xml
Find_Feed.xml                   TBT_RewardsCoreCustomer.xml

Comment: TBT_RewardsCoreSpending.xml
Fooman_Jirafe.xml                TBT_RewardsLoyalty.xml
IWD_OnepageCheckout.xml          TBT_RewardsOnly.xml
Kanavan_Searchautocomplete.xml   TBT_RewardsPlat.xml
Latitudweb_Salesanalytics.xml    TBT_RewardsReferral.xml
Lema21_CustomExport.xml          TBT_Rewardssocial.xml
Mage_All.xml                     TBT_Rewards.xml
Mage_Api2.xml                    TBT_Testsweet.xml
Mage_Api.xml                     ThemeOptions_All.xml
Mage_Authorizenet.xml            Thirty4_CatalogSale.xml
Mage_Bundle.xml                  TM_Core.xml

Comment: Mage_Bundle.xml                  TM_Core.xml
Mage_Captcha.xml                 TM_EasyTabs.xml
Mage_Centinel.xml                Unleashed_Sendinvoice.xml
Mage_Compiler.xml                Webinse_Crm.xml
Mage_Connect.xml                 Webtex_Core.xml
Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml          Webtex_Giftcards.xml
Mage_Downloadable.xml            WP_CustomMenu.xml
Mage_GoogleShopping.xml          Yumba_OrderCancel.xml
Mage_ImportExport.xml

Comment: use: lsof,fuser and strace to understand where from and why data is coming:

Comment: It does seem to be an exploit. To confirm this, you may need someone who can research into the codes and clean them up. I highly recommend the guys at Sucuri which are one of the most competent security researcher you can find (go for their Website AntiVirus): http://sucuri.net/

Comment: @SteveTallent Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not any hack happened to your website. This is because of your custom module that maybe use `catalog/image` helper methods to cache. because when the product image is cached in `media/catalog/product/cache` check its sub direcotry` its look like this..

```
/var/www/image/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/0
```

So, from this check the number in the above path `9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95` this is what writed in that file. So some of your module or maybe your core module doing this.

Its look like the image is created by `catalog/image` helper class, so the image name is "NoImages" and then name contains 100_184 so it maybe tries to `resize()` but the `x` is added  at end, usually `catalog/image` helper put `x` only for directory.

**So Think about the statements i have listed above, definitely you will solve this..**

Hope this helps to solve your problem..

Comment: good explanation, but you are way too optimistic. OP is not talking about cache folder but actual product folder.